# Define ELASTICSEARCH_URL for Kibana on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Do we have any way to set the ELASTICSEARCH_URL in Dockerfile for Kibana? This is my Dockerfile but maybe it not correct so Kibana keep showing the log that cannot find elasticsearch on localhost:9200

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.0.1
ARG ELASTICSEARCH_URL=https://myurl.com
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the reason because it said: "Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}

Comment: it meant my custom url was not applied.

Comment: Can you provide your `docker run` command for kibana and for elasticsearch.

Comment: I deployed this to Elastic Beanstalk of AWS so I write any docker run command

Answer (score 0):

that will work:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.0.1
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_URL http://test:9200
EXPOSE 80
```

so use `ENV` not `ARG`

see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.0/docker.html)

the default value is :

```
 elasticsearch.url http://elasticsearch:9200
```

and you need to make sure to setup the connection correctly between your Conatiners

Answer (score 0):

There is a new variable now in version 7.9 named `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/docker.html